# Keep track of user uploads within articles

Tags: php, mysql, wysiwyg

just can't get my head around this.

I just finished my own WYSIWYG editor. It allows my users to upload images to embed in their article they are writing.

But how can i keep track of those user uploads ? I want them to be attached to the article, so that when i remove an article all images will also be removed. (keep my disk clean)

My first bet was to add an hidden input field to the article form for every uploaded image containing the image name, then on submit move all attached images from the tmp dir to the article image dir.

But this way a user can attach 100 times a picture to an article, remove them 99 times from the WYSIWYG editor and use only 1. Now i would have to save all the unused images. This seems like waste to me.

Any best practices on this ?

Comment: How does your editor upload/attach images to begin with?

Comment: As said:
Upon (ajax) upload it appends an hidden input field to the article form. On submitting the article form, i will loop trough the hidden input fields en move the uploaded files.

Comment: any other suggestions on the upload/attaching system are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about the edge case. Nobody is going to upload then deassociate 99 images.

You have to move the received files out of the tmp dir as soon as the (ajax?) upload sends them over. You cannot wait till the article submission, because the /tmp files would be gone by then.

Try to save your images with enumerated filenames like `ArticleName.1.jpeg`. And let your WYSIWIG editor inject uniqure placeholder tokens like `{{img1}}` on which you can see which images are factuall still in the article. (You can also try to deduce the file ids out from `<img src="upl/articlename.1.jpeg"...` since your WYSIWIG editor generates HTML.)

Anyway, on upload compare the list of enumerated `{{img123}}` tokens with the existing list of files.123.jpeg. Remove the unused.

Alternative: Do not remove unused images. Sell it as feature, since you now have more article history. And I guess the filesizes are negligible for most web sites.